# Recyclerview view not populating

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm a Kotlin newbie learning how to create simple recyclerview apps. My code is supposed to list the integers 1..10 in vertically stacked cells. However, it only lists the first item. I've consulted several tutorials and reviewed my code several times(after long breaks), but I can't see anything wrong in my code.

I got the bright idea early today to print Log statements. Examining them, I note that my onBindViewHolder function is only called once. What blunder am I making?

Here is my log output:

```
D/QuoteAdapter: value is: 1
D/QuoteAdapter: index is: 0
D/QuoteAdapter: Size is: 10
```

my activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        mRecyclerView.adapter = QuoteAdapter()
        //mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    }
}
```

my adapter:

```
class QuoteAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<QuoteViewHolder>() {
    private val listOfInts = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    private val TAG = "QuoteAdapter"

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): QuoteViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item_row, parent, false)
        return QuoteViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        Log.d(TAG, "Size is: ${listOfInts.size.toString()}")
        return listOfInts.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: QuoteViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = listOfInts[position]
        Log.d(TAG, "value is: ${item.toString()}")
        Log.d(TAG, "index is: ${position.toString()}")
        holder.listTitle.text = item.toString()
    }
}
```

my viewholder:

```
class QuoteViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val listTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemString) as TextView
}
```

my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemString"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

my main layout is shown below:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can we see the xml in which your `RecyclerView` is contained?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp: the last section contains my main xml file.

Comment: Cool that code looks fine to me try my answers suggestion I think that's the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your "my layout" try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemString"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Notice `layout_height` of `LinearLayout` has changed to `wrap_content`

Also doubt you need the `android:orientation="vertical"` on your `ViewHolder`s item xml unless you will add more than just 1 `TextView` in the future.

Comment: Yes, wrap_content doesn't occupy the entire screen as match_parent does. This way onBind is called other times more

Comment: Yeah didn't test it myself but thought as much as that just doesn't seem right, and as OP said its only being called once made sense as it occupied the entire screen and Recyclerview wouldn't show or bind invisible holders

Comment: I tried it and it's this. The OP's code works fine, it's just each item is literally the size of the screen with a tiny text box at the top, you can still scroll it!

Comment: It's funny how such a small thing can have such a big effect. It works now. Thanks!

Comment: Lol it is right and how long we can spend looking for them . Glad it's working

Answer (score 3):

Like Zain says, you can just use a `TextView` on its own in a layout file, which will also fix the problem (so long as its height is `wrap_content`!)

There are actually a few included with Android - type `android.R.layout.` and you'll see a few things, like `simple_list_item_1` which is just a styled `TextView` (you can ctrl+click the reference or whatever to look at the file). Can be nice if you just want to make a quick thing!

The ID of the `TextView` in `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` is `@android:id/text1` - note the `android` prefix, because its part of the `android` resources, not your app's. Which means you have to reference the ID in the same way as the layout, with `android` at the front: `android.R.id.text1`

Comment: Nice one on the built in items +1

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the `LinearLayout` in the list item layout, and only keep the `TextView`.

So, replace your list item layout with:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/itemString"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```